# Charging 24V battery from 12V-24V converter

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter

I have a wind turbine, which generates 12V/400W and two 12V batteries connected in series to have one 24V. I have two questions, is it possible to charge them from the turbine just through the 12/24V converter without using the 24V charger? The second question: Is it possible to charge them just with the 12V from the wind turbine without using the converter at all?
The batteries must be connected in series the whole time.
Thanks in advance.[image: An approximate drawing]

Edit: The batteries are both Varta Professional DC -LFD140-12V-140AH - lead acid.

Edit2: Is there any way how to charge the batteries from the turbine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more detail but I will say that this will probably not work. I'm going to assume that your batteries are 12V lead-acid batteries, please edit your question if that is not correct.

To properly charge a 12V lead-acid battery you need a charging voltage of at least 13.8V and something like 14.4V is better. So, you would need a charging voltage of about 28V to 30V. If your 12V-24V converter really supplies 24V then it will not be able to charge the batteries.

It's worth mentioning that you need to be careful when charging batteries in series like this. A fault in one of the cells can cause all of the other cells to be overcharged and destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, finally I understand why it won't work. The I charge them now is through the 230V car battery charger, for which I have to connect another 12V to the turbine, to the battery is connected 12/230V converter and that is connected to the car battery charger. It works but is really inneficient, so I was looking for other ways how to charge it.